# Given $g(2)=3$ and $f(4)=3$ find $k$ in $g\left(\frac{x+3}{x-1}\right)= f\left(\frac{kx-2}{x-k}\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Given $g(2)=3$ and $f(4)=3$,
>   find $k$ in: $$g\left(\frac{x+3}{x-1}\right)= f\left(\frac{kx-2}{x-k}\right)$$

I have solved this problem and the answer is $\frac {22}9$, however, since $g$ and $f$ are different functions, why do we solve the equation by using the $x$ value of the function $g?$

Does the domain of $g$ and $f$ consist of the $x$ values?

Comment: Hi! Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make your post pretty!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Set $$\dfrac{x+3}{x-1}=2\iff x=?$$ and $$\dfrac{kx-2}{x-k}=4$$ and replace the value of $x$

Comment: Is that solution unique?  Suppose both functions are constant of value $3$?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe, Otherwise $g(2)=3=f(4)$ do not make much sense, right?

Comment: There are a lot of different ways to get to the number 3. Many functions will have the image of 3 for some element of the domain